# Ez Publish - Which files should I edit to control the Upload mechanism

Tags: file-upload, ezpublish

I'm new to Ez Publish. I need to change the behaviour of the File Upload mechanism in the Ez Publish.

I'm kind of lost in which files should I edit.

Can someone give me a clue?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is the `upload.ini` file you should modify. An override of it, to be more accurate ([more on overrides here](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Concepts-and-basics/Configuration#eztoc86631_2) ). That would affect the built-in upload mechanism.

As an illustration of how one can extend the built-in behaviour, the [eZODF](https://github.com/ezsystems/ezodf) extension provides a [new set of upload handlers](https://github.com/ezsystems/ezodf/tree/master/uploadhandlers), configured in an [override of upload.ini](https://github.com/ezsystems/ezodf/blob/master/settings/upload.ini.append.php).

Tip : you can come-by on the [eZ Publish Community portal](http://share.ez.no) to ask such questions too, more eZ Publish people are wired-in there.

Cheers,